# dandelion datatables scrollX doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, dandelion

I have a table with many columns so I would like to add a scrollX ability (scroll right and left) using dandelion datatables as following:

```
<div class="container">
    <jsp:include page="../fragments/bodyHeader.jsp"/>
    <datatables:table id="listDbResultItem" data="${listDbResultItem}" row="dbResultItem" scrollX="200">
        <datatables:column title="Target Name" property="targetName"/>
        .
        .
        .
    </datatables:table>
</div
```

I tried several variations but the scroll bar doesn't appear... Any idea?

Dandelion version:
0.10.0

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `scrollX` attribute is actually a CSS unit. If it's a number, the value is treated as a pixel measurement. See http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/docs/ref/jsp/table.html#scrollX

Try to set the value in percentage:

```
<datatables:table ... scrollX="200%">
   ...
</datatables:table>
```

Side note: please precise the version of Dandelion-Datatables.

Comment: Hi, I put `200%` but it doesn't work. from pom.xml: `<dandelion.version>0.10.0</dandelion.version>`. note that I don't have nothing related to dandelion in the `ready` method. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `cssClass="table` to the table deceleration solved the problem.

Thanks,